# Swift - UIProgressView becomes more opaque as time goes on

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiprogressview

So I have a UIProgressView which animates for 3 seconds but it seems that the opacity of the bar at the start, is much lower than at the end. The bar seems to become more opaque as it loads. I have attached some screenshots to show what I mean but I simply can't work out why this is. Is it a characteristic of the loading bar or is it an Xcode bug? Don't think there's anything wrong with the code as it's pretty simple really:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
        })
```

Anyway here are the screenshots to better demonstrate the issue:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this is how progress view works.

Comment: Ah ok. Does seem strange though