# UIProgressView become transparent during setProgress with animated = true

Tags: swift, xcode, uiprogressview, ios15

In iOS15 UIProgressView changed behavior. When I use `self.progress.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)`, it starts from transparent style. How to return to "alpha = 1" style.

1. [progress = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0sUz.png)
2. [progress = 20%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgusK.png)
3. [progress = 70%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhOuX.png)
4. [progress = 90%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Ja2.png)

P.S.: progress.alpha = 1 does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449162/swift-uiprogressview-becomes-more-opaque-as-time-goes-on Doesn't really seem like it's something that happend in iOS 15?

Comment: @Vollan it worked fine on previous iOS versions... (

Comment: @DanKamilov hey have you solved it? I'm facing that issue in iOS 15 as well

Answer (score 2):

Setting a tintImage with a UIImage extension with color works. This seemed to be the easiest way for me to remove that transparency.

```
progressView.progressImage = UIImage(color: progressTintColor)
```

UIImage extension

```
extension UIImage {
convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change this opaque/transparent behavior is to use your own Timer.

```
private let progressUnit = Progress(totalUnitCount: 20)

func startAnimate(){
        self.progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
        self.progressUnit.completedUnitCount = 0
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { timer in
            guard self.progressUnit.isFinished == false else{
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            
            self.progressUnit.completedUnitCount += 1
            let progressFloat = Float(self.progressUnit.fractionCompleted)
            self.progressView.setProgress(progressFloat, animated: true)
        }
    }
```